# check if I stayed in the same page or not

Tags: php, behat, mink

I use mink to test a website and I want to write a test scenario to check for error scenarios. So I want to see If I insert invalid data a page should return error and I should be in the same page as before. I mean I don't want to go to another page.
for that I wrote a test scenario like below:

```
some steps ....
And Save current page
some other steps....
Then I should stay in the same page
```

for the two steps I wrote to method like beloww:

```
/**
 * @Given /^Save current page$/
 */
public function SaveCurrentPage() {
    $this->_last_page = $this->getSession ()->getCurrentUrl ();
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @Given /^I should stay in the same page$/
 */
public function StayInSamePage() {
    if ($this->_last_page === null) {
        throw new FailureException ( "current page is not defined" );
        // throw new Exception ( "current page is not defined" );
    }
    if ($this->_last_page !== $this->getSession ()->getCurrentUrl ()) {

        throw new FailureException ( "you should be in " . $this->_last_page . " but you are in  " . $this->getSession ()->getCurrentUrl () );
        // throw new Exception ( "you should be in " . $this->_last_page . " but you are in " . $this->getSession ()->getCurrentUrl () );
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

But I really don't like my solution. Since the line Save current page does'nt relate to the behavior of the application and is only used for mink and I think is not what behat/mink's goal is.
Is there any better solution? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Store the last visited page in the step you open it.

Comment: thank you @JakubZalas I actually didn't know that it would be this much easy. Thank you.

Comment: I just have an other question. For restoring the last page in previous step I should redefine all steps like "I go to" or "I follow to". Is it right?